# How to enable SSL for a Qt Linux application?

Tags: qt, ssl, openssl

Hi I'm just trying to get the stock example securesocketclient to work in a linux environment. I tried compiling it and running but QSslSocket::supportsSsl() returns false.

I want to know something very very simple, for which I cannot find a definitive answer: Must I compile my own version of Qt in order to get SSL support? If not, can some one give me the steps to actually enable SSL support. Most answers I found focus only on Windows, and I need to make it work on Linux.

Comment: Solved it!! I had to download the development files. For debian testing this package libssl1.0-dev

Answer (score 1):

(Adding the answer to search engine's sake, even though you found it by yourself :) )

Yes you need the development package for that, in order to have the right headers available. The same applies other Qt modules with external dependencies like gstreamer.